# Counterintuitive result while computing Kolmogorov Complexity

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, information-theory

I need help with a counterintuitive result that I found regarding computing Kolmogorov Complexities.

Suppose two strings, being s1:

> 5p$j3

and s2:

> ababab

I want to compute the Kolmogorov Complexity of s1 and of s2, that is, K(s1) and K(s2).

In pseudo-code, we could have for s1:

> return "5p$j3"

such as K(s1) = 14.

And also in pseudo-code, we could have for s2:

> return "ababab"

such as K(s2) = 15.

It is possible to also do:

> return "ab" x 3

Which would also give K(s2) = 15.

Intuitively, you would think that algorithmic complexity would be greater for s1 than s2, that, by itself, looks much more simpler, but K(s2) > K(s1) as far as I could go.

How to explain this result? Is "ababab", considering the computation of Kolmogorov Complexity, actually more algorithmically complex than "5p$j3"? Maybe there is another way to write the "ababab" string so it actually computes a lower value for K(s2)?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The compression gets much more significant if you compress , say $abab\cdots abab$ with $100$ 'ab' 's.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Indeed, I was just wondering about the complexity of some string that wouldn't really benefit much from compression but, at the same time, could be intuitively considered simpler than another (shorter) string.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the Kolomogorov complexity is uncomputable , in general we cannot prove that a string cannot be significantly compressed although long random strings almost always are virtually incompressible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make a lot of sense to compute Kolmogorov Complexity for one specific string, because it depends on programming language. For example, we can take some random string $s$ of length $10^{100}$, some universal decompressor, and create new decompressor, that outputs $s$ if the first bit of input is $0$, otherwise drops the first bit of input and launches universal decompressor - this also will be a universal decompressor, but complexity of $s$ by it will be just $1$.

What makes more sense is to speak about asymptotic behaviour of Kolmogorov complexity. For example, Kolmogorov complexity of string $(ab)^n$ ($ab$ repeated $n$ times) is at most $\log_2 n + C$, where $C$ doesn't depend on $n$, while complexity of most strings of length $2n$ is at least $2n$ - so, if you take $n$ large enough, you will get that $(ab)^n$ is simpler than most of strings of the same length.

Comment: Thank you very much. This makes a lot of sense.